# MATLAB: How do I combine a structure array with same size field values into one structure

Tags: matlab, structure

I have a structure array where each field of the same name is the same size. I want to combine each field over the array into one field. For example:

```
A(1).x = [1 2 3];
A(1).y = [4 5 6];
A(2).x = [7 8 9];
A(2).y = [10 11 12];
```

I want the new structure to be

```
B.x = [1 2 3;
       7 8 9];
B.y = [4 5 6;
       10 11 12];
```

These could also be a cell of structures if that makes things easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A.x` produces a comma-separated list of values. You can use this comma-separated list in a function call, in which case each value is treated as a separate argument. This is very useful, as you can pass it into a call to `cat` to concatenate the values:

```
B.x = cat(1, A.x);
```

You'd have to do this same operation for each of the fields. To automate this you could iterate over `fieldnames(A)`:

```
for name = fieldnames(A).'
   B.(name{1}) = cat(1, A.(name{1}));
end
```

Comment: I tried that using `vertcat` and an error came out `Argument to dynamic structure reference must evaluate to a valid field name.` i think I need to do it this way. `fields = fieldnames(A);
for i = 1:length(fields)                   
    B.(fields{i}) = vertcat(A.(fields{i}));
end`

Comment: @Shelley: You're right, I forgot that MATLAB does this when iterating over a cell array. I've edited the code, should be correct now. Your way to iterate is correct as well. I'd use `numel` instead of `length`. I like to avoid `length` because it is such a strange function that causes strange errors at times. But it's definitely OK to use in this case.

Comment: I tried your revision and it concatenates the first fieldname only.

Comment: @Shelley: Ah, `fieldnames` returns a column vector of names, I assumed it would be a row vector. The transpose I've added to the code fixes this. I've finally tested this myself, the current version is correct. Sorry for the mistakes.